# Is my SSD drive going bad? SMART error

Tags: ssd, smart

Is there something wrong with my SSD drive ? It's still under warranty so I can replace it ;)

```
SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 1
        CR = Command Register [HEX]
        FR = Features Register [HEX]
        SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
        SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
        CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
        CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
        DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
        DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
        ER = Error register [HEX]
        ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 1 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1537 hours (64 days + 1 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle
.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 00 00 00 00 00

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:19:35.000  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  e5 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff      00:19:34.500  CHECK POWER MODE
  b0 da 00 00 4f c2 00 00      00:17:57.100  SMART RETURN STATUS
  ef 02 00 00 00 00 a0 00      00:17:57.100  SET FEATURES [Enable write cache]
  ef aa 00 00 00 00 a0 00      00:17:57.100  SET FEATURES [Enable read look-ahea
d]
```

More generally: Are there specific techniques for SMART on SSD drives?

Comment: *"Here's a wall of text, do I have a problem?"* isn't one of the best presentation methods. In future questions, try to identify what it is you saw within the output that caused you to be concerned.

Comment: Look at the error message at the end.

Comment: I can find the error. My point was more that if your presentation requires people to search the entire output to find the message that *may* be concerning you, many people aren't going to take the time to look for it.

Comment: Edited my message. Please check again.

Comment: That's a little bit better. Note that the detailed output wasn't necessarily a bad thing, it's just a good idea to identify *outside* of it what message was concerning you so that people have a point of reference.

Comment: Actually I found the full output very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know, if ssds support this, but for a normal hdd, if you suspect a problem, you let it do a short or long selftest:

```
smartctl -t short /dev/sdX
# or
smartctl -t long /dev/sdX
```

It will normally tell you how long this takes. Leave you computer on for that time. Then check the result with `smartctl -a /dev/sdX`. I recommend keeping a trail of `smartctl -a` outputs somewhere to compare what changed.

All that said, I really don't know, what SSDs these days support when it comes to smart. The last time I had an SSD connected to my main box, its smart was… well, it could use some improvement.

Comment: # 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1707         -

Comment: Did any other attributes change? That might help identify possible issues.

Comment: No, only that one ;)

Comment: # 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      1711         -

Comment: That sounds good. I'd say, the above error was temporary. Maybe the cable? Keep an eye on the smartctl -a output and watch for new errors. Also take a snapshot once a while so you can compare the attributes. (ps: Can you accept and/or upvote my answer?)

Comment: You've got my vote

Comment: How do you access smartctl?   I posted that as a question:
http://superuser.com/questions/884067/how-do-i-access-smartctl-on-windows-7