# How do I access SmartCtl on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I've got an SSD that may be going bad.
A [SU answer suggested using Smartctl](https://superuser.com/a/576195/5001) but I don't know how to access that.
(It's not available on the command line)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its not part of the default windows install. Its a third party software that's meant for linux, though [there's a windows port](http://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Download#InstalltheWindowspackage).

I prefer [gsmartctl](http://gsmartcontrol.sourceforge.net/home/index.php/Downloads), which is a nice little graphical front end for it which includes a windows port. There's a few others mentioned which may work on the smartmontools page as well.

However you're almost certainly better off using *tools for the specific SSD* in question - many manufacturers include tools that let you do things like manage free space and diagnostics - My samsung uses magician, but your exact tool would vary.

Comment: If you include the link I posted in my answer, below, I'll mark your answer as THE answer.
GREAT tip for using the SSD-specific tool. I'd **bold** that.

Comment: I have Samsung as well... so downloading Magician. To document this problem and solution better, I posted a better question: http://superuser.com/questions/884073/how-do-i-check-the-health-of-my-samsung-ssd  which you are welcome to answer. Magician is : http://goo.gl/q8JLgo

Comment: Its really in essence the same question though. I'd rather have the specific details edited in here.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Download#InstalltheWindowspackage

> After installation or booting from a Live-CD, you can read
>   smartmontools man pages and try out the commands:
>
> man smartd.conf   man smartctl   man smartd
>        sudo /usr/sbin/smartctl -s on -o on -S on /dev/sda   sudo /usr/sbin/smartctl -x /dev/sda

Comment: Erm, was this supposed to be a comment or edit?

Comment: link is dead...