# How do I check the health of my Samsung SSD?

Tags: windows-7, ssd

I've got a Samsung SSD on Windows that's giving CHKDSK errors.
How do I check the health?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Samsung Magician Software

From [Samsung SSD Downloads](https://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/global/html/support/downloads.html):

> The Magician SSD management utility is designed to work with all Samsung SSD products including 470 Series, 750 Series, 830 Series, 840 Series, 850 Series, 860 Series, 870 Series, 960 Series, 970 Series and 980 Series. This software is not compatible with other manufacturers' SSDs.

From the Samsung Magician Introduction and Installation Guide:

> The Samsung Magician software is designed to help users easily manage the health and performance of their Samsung SSD. In addition to providing vital SSD health status information, Magician will assist users in updating firmware, measuring performance, and optimizing the configuration of a Windows operating system installation.

Samsung Magician software from the [Samsung SSD Downloads](https://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/global/html/support/downloads.html) website. The latest version of Magician software is recommended for optimal performance.

The latest version of the Samsung Magician Introduction and Installation Guide can be downloaded from [here](https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81idQIwpLpS.pdf). Samsung frequently updates the Samsung Magician Introduction and Installation Guide, so if the link doesn't work anymore, you can also find the Samsung Magician Introduction and Installation Guide by googling it.

Comment: Samsung and Intel are the only two manufacturers of SSDs that have TRIM support enabled on Ubuntu by default.

Comment: Samsung Magician will not install on my Windows 10 system.  Even when I run the installer as an administrator, I just see a console window flash on the screen and then vanish.  Nothing happens.  The program just won't install.

Comment: The latest version of Samsung Magician from the official Samsung website is version 4.8. Microsoft Forum: [Samsung Magician software doesn't recognize Windows 10, wont initialize RAPID mode](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_devices/samsung-magician-software-doesnt-recognize-windows/707d1eda-d840-4a89-9a57-bc82023a8860?auth=1) discusses compatibility issues with Samsung Magician in Windows 10.